# STM32 - can't open serial port from pyserial, but can from ST-Link

Tags: python, stm32, pyserial, nucleo

I'm working with STM32 (NUCLEO-L476RG) - uploading code via Workbench, sometimes using ST-Link Utility to connect to it.
Additionally, I've some python code that listens to STM via serial port.

Till yesterday everything was working fine, but today (without changing anything connected to STM, drivers etc.) **pyserial can't connect to the device**, showing message:

`File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM7': FileNotFoundError(2, 'Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.', None, 2)`

**I can upload code using Workbench or connect to STM via ST-Link Utility without any problems. Port is not used by any other application.**

When I list ports by `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` it shows properly as `STMicroelectronics STLink Virtual COM Port (COM7)`.

In 'Device Manager' there's a yellow triangle next to the COM, but I'm not sure if it were there earlier (probably yes) - it says that the device driver is not signed.

[image: device]

I tried to:

- reinstall the drivers to these provided by STM
- reinstall pyserial
- use older python
- use older pyserial
- change COM to another
- change cable to new one
- connect the device to all possible USB ports

but any of that changed anything.

My setup:

- Windows 7
- python 3.7.1
- pyserial 3.4
- STM 32 NUCLEO-L476RG
- System Workbench for STM32 & ST-Link Utility, which are working perfectly fine

This setup was working for half a year (!) and I didn't change anything connected to it in the last couple of days. Only thing I did yesterday was installing PostgreSQL, but it seems highly unbelievable that it could cause my current problem...

Thank you in advance for any help - I don't really have an idea what should I try next, so I appreciate any piece of advice.

Comment: Please post the code, at least where you are opening the port.

Comment: Python level error is not relevant. What is the error code in Device Manager exactly? Also, try to connect it to Win10, with its in-box CDC driver. Win10 may provide more detailed error info. Windows update could clobber a good working driver... it happens.

Comment: @MichaelO. code is good. It was working earlier.

Comment: @ddbug - there's an error in Device Manager about "not signed certificates" - error 52. On Win10 everything works fine, but I'm not gonna update to it :)